# Synchronize users in DNN and Microsoft Dynamics CRM

Tags: .net, dynamics-crm, dotnetnuke

I am using DNN (Dotnetnuke), I have created a website using it. Where users signup and login and manage their account on this site. I am also using Microsoft Dynamics CRM with this website so I have to create users on CRM too . Which creates a problem of Synchronization, users data must be Synchronize all time in CRM and DNN. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

There are many methods that can be used for this, however, the key is going to be understanding who is responsible for the data.  If the users are actually registering in DNN & you are updating it could be possible to use DNN as the source of record.

In the end, you will need to establish a two-way synchronization between both DNN & Dynamics.  The full logistics of this will vary greatly and is far beyond the scope of an answer here on Stack Overflow.

If you can get a bit more outlined on the needed data flows, we might be able to pinpoint things more.